# Bucles y vincular marcos de datos para pronósticos usando prophet

Tags: r, funciones, bucle-for, condiciones, else

library(prophet)

Buenas tardes, tengo aproximadamente 16.986 series de tiempo, los pronósticos los estoy sacando con prophet, cada serie de tiempo tiene una observaciones mensuales de los últimos 3 años, es decir, la primera observación es en "2015-12-01", la segunda es en "2016-01-01" y así sucesivamente hasta la observación 36 (la última) que corresponde a la fecha "2018-11-01". Pero no todas las series tiene 36 observaciones.

El marco de datos requerido por prophet para realizar el pronostico debe tener la siguiente característica: la variable fecha debe llamarse "ds" y estar en formato fecha, y las observaciones se colocan en la variable "y".

Como tengo 16.986 Series, cree una columna llamada Code, donde cada Serie esta enumerada desde el 1 hasta el 16.986, teniendo finalmente 611.496 observaciones. mi data frame para "Series" se ve de la siguiente forma:

[image: Series]

Como necesito realizar los pronósticos para las 16.986 observaciones y guardar los resultados, utilicé el siguiente bucle:

Donde:

"Series": son los datos.
"Series": son los datos.

```
    n = as.numeric(max(Series$Code)) 

analyze <- function(pronostico){
  for(i in 1:n){
    m <- prophet(Series %>% filter(Code == i))
    future_df_prophet <- make_future_dataframe(m, periods = 6, freq = "month")
            Pronostico <- tail(predict(m, future_df_prophet))
    Pronostico$Code <- i
    if (i == 1){
  out <- Pronostico
} else {
  out <- dplyr::bind_rows(out, Pronostico)
}
  }
  return(out)
}

system.time(PronosticoProphet <- analyze(pronostico))
```

El proceso se realizó bien la primera vez para 11.000 series, pero ahora sólo hace el análisis para 3.000 y se queda pegado, es decir, no hace ningún otro proceso.

Espero que entiendan lo que quiero decir y lo que debo conseguir al final. Gracias por la ayuda que me puedan dar.

Comment: Obviamente no puedo probar con tus datos, pero probé igual tu código con un  `data.frame` "dummy" del tamaño y características que mencionas  y funciono bastantes horas pero funcionó bien. ¿Te ha dado algún error que puedas agregar a tu pregunta? ¿Has probado actualizar los paquetes?

Comment: Hola, pues el proceso simplemente se detiene y R queda pegado no veo que pase nada, lo que hice ahora para determinar donde tengo el problema, es no utilizar ninguna función, sólo el for y además agregué avisos linea por línea, todavía estoy esperando a ver que pasa.

Comment: Es una buena medida Marhysol, al menos para saber dónde ocurre el error. El comportamiento que comentas es totalmente anormal, e imposible de analizar lamentablemente.